# Form inputs with sweet alert and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, if-statement

I have a form with two states. In first state required inputs are fill and in the second state are empty. I use sweet alert to show result of input, but if-else don´t work properly. My form code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.css"/>
       <form method='post'>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" autofocus required placeholder="Escribe tu nombre (Obligatorio)"/>
            <br>
            <input type="mail" name="mail" id ="mail" required placeholder="Escribe tu correo (Obligatorio)">
            <br>
            <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Escribe tu teléfono" />
            <br>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="35" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje (Obligatorio)"  /></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

And my jquery code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
                    $("#enviar").click(function () {
                    if ($("#nombre").is(':empty')){
                        swal({
                            title: "Datos incorrectos.",
                            text: "No se ha enviado el correo.",
                            type: "warning", 
                            allowOutsideClick: false,
                            timer:5000,
                        });
                    }
                if ($("#nombre").not(':empty')){
                 swal({
                    title: "Correcto.",
                    text: "Se ha enviado el correo.",
                    type: "success", 
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    timer:5000,

                });
             }
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see `if-else` in your code.

Comment: Replace the `if ($("#nombre").not(':empty'))` with `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#enviar").click(function (event) {
      
      if ($("#nombre").val()) {
        swal({
          title: "Correcto.",
          text: "Se ha enviado el correo.",
          type: "success", 
          allowOutsideClick: false,
         timer:5000,
        });
      }
      else {
        swal({
          title: "Datos incorrectos.",
          text: "No se ha enviado el correo.",
          type: "warning", 
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          timer:5000,
        });
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.5.0/sweet-alert.css"/>
       <form method='post'>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" autofocus required placeholder="Escribe tu nombre (Obligatorio)"/>
            <br>
            <input type="mail" name="mail" id ="mail" required placeholder="Escribe tu correo (Obligatorio)">
            <br>
            <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Escribe tu teléfono" />
            <br>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="35" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje (Obligatorio)"  /></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

I used `$("#element").val()` which return true if the val is not empty, false if it is empty.